# Phone directory application to add contacts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

Recently i was taking some challenges on hackerrank for phone directory.
The code is running fine on my local system but when compling through their web IDE it throws an error or it's not being validated.

Code is here

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Phone Directory</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        
        .layout-column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        .justify-content-center {
            justify-content: center;
        }
        
        .mt-75 {
            margin-top: 75px;
        }
        
        .mx-auto {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .mt-30 {
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        
        .w-75 {
            width: 75%;
        }
        
        .contacts-card {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .ml-30 {
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        
        #summaryTable {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        
        #summaryTable th,
        #summaryTable td {
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        
        #error {
            display: none;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="layout-column justify-content-center mt-75">
        <div class="mx-auto">
            <input type="text" id="name" data-testid="name" value="" placeholder="Contact Name" />
            <input type="text" id="mobile" data-testid="mobile" value="" placeholder="Mobile Number" />
            <input type="email" id="email" data-testid="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
            <button type="submit" id="submit" data-testid="submit" class="small">
        Add Contact
      </button>
            <div id="error" data-testid="error" class="error text-center error alert mx-75 mt-30">
                Invalid Input!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mx-auto mt-30 w-75 contacts-card">
            <h4 class="ml-30" id="contactsSummary">Contacts Summary</h4>
            <div id="contactSummary" class="contactSummary">
                <table id="summaryTable" data-testid="summaryTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th id="nameColumn">Name</th>
                            <th id="mobileColumn">Mobile</th>
                            <th id="emailColumn">Email</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Contact rows will be dynamically added here -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        'use strict';

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission

            // Get input values
            var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
            var mobileInput = document.getElementById('mobile');
            var emailInput = document.getElementById('email');

            // Get error message element
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('error');

            // Reset error message
            errorElement.style.display = 'none';

            // Validate name
            var name = nameInput.value.trim();
            if (name === '') {
                showError();
                return;
            }
            if (!/^[A-Za-z\s]{1,20}$/.test(name)) {
                showError();
                return;
            }

            // Validate mobile
            var mobile = mobileInput.value.trim();
            if (mobile === '') {
                showError();
                return;
            }
            if (!/^\d{10}$/.test(mobile)) {
                showError();
                return;
            }

            // Validate email
            var email = emailInput.value.trim();
            if (email === '') {
                showError();
                return;
            }
            if (!/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]{1,10}@[A-Za-z]{2,20}\.[A-Za-z]{2,10}$/.test(email)) {
                showError();
                return;
            }

            // All validations passed, add contact to the table
            addContactToTable(name, mobile, email);

            // Clear input fields
            nameInput.value = '';
            mobileInput.value = '';
            emailInput.value = '';

            // Hide error message
            errorElement.style.display = 'none';
        });

        function showError() {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('error');
            errorElement.style.display = 'block';
        }

        function addContactToTable(name, mobile, email) {
            var tableBody = document.querySelector('#summaryTable tbody');

            var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            var nameCell = document.createElement('td');
            var mobileCell = document.createElement('td');
            var emailCell = document.createElement('td');

            nameCell.textContent = name;
            mobileCell.textContent = mobile;
            emailCell.textContent = email;

            newRow.appendChild(nameCell);
            newRow.appendChild(mobileCell);
            newRow.appendChild(emailCell);

            tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

FAIL test/test.js (22.312 s)

Phone Directory

```
✕ should show error when input fields are empty (5006 ms)

✕ should show error when Invalid Inputs are given (5005 ms)

✕ should add the contact on clicking Add Contact (5004 ms)

✕ should reset after adding a contact (5003 ms)
```

● Phone Directory › should show error when input fields are empty

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

  at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:27:45)
```

● Phone Directory › should show error when input fields are empty

```
TypeError: The provided value is not of type 'Element'.

  19 | 

  20 | const getComputedStyle = (node) => {

> 21 |     return dom.window.getComputedStyle(node, null)

     |                       ^

  22 | }

  23 | 

  24 | 

  at Object.<anonymous>.exports.convert (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Element.js:26:9)

  at getComputedStyle (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:644:19)

  at getComputedStyle (test/test.js:21:23)

  at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.js:73:25)
```

● Phone Directory › should show error when Invalid Inputs are given

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

  at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:27:45)
```

● Phone Directory › should show error when Invalid Inputs are given

```
Unable to fire a "input" event - please provide a DOM element.

  41 | 

  42 |     const addInput = (input, text) => {

> 43 |         fireEvent.input(input, {

     |                   ^

  44 |             target: {value: text}

  45 |         })

  46 |         fireEvent.change(input, {

  at createEvent (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:34:11)

  at Function.createEvent.<computed> [as input] (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:120:38)

  at Function.input (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:125:68)

  at addInput (test/test.js:43:19)

  at _callee2$ (test/test.js:82:9)

  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)

  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)

  at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)

  at asyncGeneratorStep (test/test.js:19:103)

  at _next (test/test.js:21:194)

  at test/test.js:21:364

  at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.js:21:97)
```

● Phone Directory › should add the contact on clicking Add Contact

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

  at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:27:45)
```

● Phone Directory › should add the contact on clicking Add Contact

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined

  67 |     })

  68 | 

> 69 |     const getTableBody = () => table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

     |                                      ^

  70 | 

  71 | 

  72 |     it('should show error when input fields are empty', () => {

  at getTableBody (test/test.js:69:38)

  at _callee3$ (test/test.js:150:16)

  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)

  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)

  at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)

  at asyncGeneratorStep (test/test.js:19:103)

  at _next (test/test.js:21:194)

  at test/test.js:21:364

  at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.js:21:97)
```

● Phone Directory › should reset after adding a contact

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

  at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:27:45)
```

● Phone Directory › should reset after adding a contact

```
Unable to fire a "input" event - please provide a DOM element.

  41 | 

  42 |     const addInput = (input, text) => {

> 43 |         fireEvent.input(input, {

     |                   ^

  44 |             target: {value: text}

  45 |         })

  46 |         fireEvent.change(input, {

  at createEvent (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:34:11)

  at Function.createEvent.<computed> [as input] (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:120:38)

  at Function.input (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:125:68)

  at addInput (test/test.js:43:19)

  at _callee4$ (test/test.js:193:9)

  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)

  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:22)

  at Generator.next (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:118:21)

  at asyncGeneratorStep (test/test.js:19:103)

  at _next (test/test.js:21:194)

  at test/test.js:21:364

  at Object.<anonymous> (test/test.js:21:97)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total

Tests:       4 failed, 4 total

Snapshots:   0 total

Time:        23.136 s

Ran all test suites.

Comment: You should make an error from what the unit tests are testing. You need to write code exactly the same as the unit test. I would just ask HackerRank support, wince without seeing the unit test no one can help you, and they are probably hidden from users.